# How To Set Background Image with UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a tinder clone that I bootstrapped from this github repo [ZLSwipeableView](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift).

I want to replace the default background colors with images from my xcassets. So far I've been able to do a pattern image but that's no good, I need to somehow use UIImageView to create a backgroundImage. This is what I have so far:

```
    let cardView = CardView(frame: swipeableView.bounds)

    if let image = UIImage(named: "Image") {
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    } else {
        print("There was no such image.")
    }
```

Then the CardView class

```
    class CardView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        // Shadow
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5)
        layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        // Corner Radius
        layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    }
}
```

Obviously each card "frame" is set up to handle colors with the `UIColor` class. How can I convert this CardView frame to a `UIImageView` object so that I can set `backgroundImage?`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a UIImageView as a subview to your CardView

```
var image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Image.png")
var labelBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>))
labelBackground = image
cardView.addSubview(labelBackground)
```

Comment: This is Swift? I get a couple of errors, commas expected and such.

Comment: sorry it was objective-c now updated with swift code, not an swift expert though

Comment: I don't know where to add this code. In the CardView class? Or in the controller

Comment: in the controller after creating your CardView class object.

Comment: Error on the 2nd line: Value of type 'ZLSwipeableViewController' has no member 'bounds'. 

I think the frame is already declared in the CardView class.

Comment: you don't have to use self.bound to get the x,y coordinates. that is just an example. Please provide x,y coordinates are per your view placement I've updated my sample. those are only placeholders, please replace with real values.

Comment: How can I get the x,y coordinates of the CardView frame?